# How can I generate an array of samples from a poisson distribution in python using jax (jit)?

Tags: python, jit, poisson

I am using jax (https://github.com/google/jax) to code up a neural network, and to simulate my inputs I would like to generate an array of samples from a poisson distribution. How can I do this given jax's restrictions?

I have already tried using np.random.poisson(mu,N) and scipy.stats.poisson.rvs(mu, size=N). Neither of these work because they are not supported in jax.numpy and jax.scipy.stats. So basically, I need an alternative solution, either with another package that jax does support or by hard-coding the poisson function.

```
from jax import jit, vmap
import jax.numpy as np
import numpy as onp
from scipy.stats import poisson

def build_input_and_targets_simulated(ntime, key):
    """
    Function: Simulate inputs and targets.
    Args:
        ntime: number of time steps in input
        key: key for random number generator
    Returns:
        inputs: txu matrix of inputs
        targets: txu matrix of target classifications
    """
    mu = 0.03  # average number of events per interval

    # scipy method
    inputs = np.array([poisson.rvs(mu, size=ntime), poisson.rvs(mu, 
size=ntime)]).T

    # numpy method
    inputs = np.array([onp.random.poisson(mu, ntime), 
onp.random.poisson(mu, ntime)]).T

    targets = onp.zeros((ntime,1))

    # determine target based on difference in inputs
    diffT = np.cumsum(inputs[:,0]) - np.cumsum(inputs[:,1]) # calculate 
cumulative difference in inputs for each time point

    targets[diffT > 0] = 1 # if diffT > 0, set binary choice
    targets[diffT ==0] = int(random.randint(key, (1,1), 0, 2)) # if 
inputs are equal, select target class randomly

    return inputs, targets

# Now batch it and jit.
build_input_and_target = build_input_and_targets_simulated
build_inputs_and_targets = vmap(build_input_and_target, in_axes=(None, 
0))
build_inputs_and_targets_jit = jit(build_inputs_and_targets, 
static_argnums=(0,))


seed = onp.random.randint(0, 1000000)
key = random.PRNGKey(seed)
ntimesteps = 25

inputs, targets = build_inputs_and_targets_jit(ntimesteps, key)
```

If I use the scipy method, I get an error that looks like this:

```
Exception: Tracer can't be used with raw numpy functions. You might have
  import numpy as np
instead of
  import jax.numpy as np
```

If I use the numpy method, I get an error that looks like this:

```
TypeError: 'BatchTracer' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Both of these errors appear to be related to the specialized data types that jax uses (and which are necessary when using jit).

How can I get around this??

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
jax.random.poisson(key, 5.1, (10,5))
```